# Remove the [guide]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request, retag-request

Some of [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/guide) has questions about [matlab-guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab-guide) and should be retagged ([query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/guide+matlab)) while the rest (from my quick scan) should be removed [as was the case with [guidance]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210724).

Comment: Same effort a year later, caught up an additional year later: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290063/5067311