# Split [guide] into more specific tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, clean-up

The tag [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/guide) is used in 2 ways:

- for documentation questions like [installation guides](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=-%5Bmatlab%5D+%5Bguide%5D+installation+is%3Aq), **10** search results right now. [Guide for working with Linux thread priorities and scheduling policies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28181758) is a good sample of it.
- for [Matlab related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bguide%5D+matlab+is%3Aq), **108** search results right now. [Where are the properties of GUI elements stored while using GUIDE (MATLAB GUI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29507644) is a good sample of it. Many of them also use the (pretty popular) [matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab) tag, but [there are a few](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bguide%5D+-%5Bmatlab%5D+matlab+is%3Aq) which are not ...

I'm not familiar (yet) with which approach is most appropriate (please teach me where to find the answer ...), but probably a combination of one or more of these actions is appropriate:

1. Create a new tag for the "documentation"-type guide questions.
2. Retag documentation-type guide questions from guide to that new tag.
3. Rename guide (like to Matlab-guide ?) and/or enhance its tag wiki / excerpt to better illustrate its use for Matlab related questions.
4. Maybe blacklist guide (whatever "blacklist" actually means here on SO, not sure how that is technically implemented).
5. Making 'guide' a synonym of some other relevant tag does NOT seem to me like helpful here.

**Note**: to make things worse: look at [guides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/guides) ... Similar, but smaller set of questions suffering a similar issue: are guides like documentation, or like lines or something? Should I ask a similar question about that one?

Bottomline: I'd appreciate to be guide**d** to get this sorted out ...

Comment: Some of those questions looking for external guides or resources / documentation can probably be closed because they are off-topic.

Comment: Agree, go ahead, be my guest (I don't have enough rep I believe ...)

Comment: You can _flag_, and it will give you the appropriate options under Other Reasons > Off-topic Because...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens just did a few, starting with "there are a few which are not".  Added matlab where appropriate.  I'll keep chipping away at them, it looks like you should be able to handle the ones where there are also improvements that can be made to the questions, which should net you some good rep, as per  Artjom B.  Feel free to ping me with any thorny ones.  I wonder if we should have a chat room to run this?  Could be fun.

Comment: OK, count me in for those where I see improvements that can be made. Let's say until I run in 1 rejected edit. what I mean: I'd be happy to contribute some help, but NOT at the price were anybody thinks I'm doing so to gain "some" rep (that is not why I'm on any SE, trust me). The chatroom I'm not sure about (yet), mostly because I don't have a lot of experience with that, except (a) one cannot delete ANY chats there, like you can if you use comments to chat (right?) and (b) I have a hard time reading those extremely small fonts over there, am I the only one?

Comment: I just realised I had forgotten the 'is:q' in my 2 queries, so I updated the links now, and the (reduced) nr of questions for each.

Comment: OK, all cleared (approved) so far ... And I've submitted a wiki tag suggestion for tag ... "guide" (with 1 approve so far). Thanks for those who approved (and overruled where needed). With that, the "10" questions have now been reduced to 4 more left ... http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=-%5Bmatlab%5D+%5Bguide%5D+installation+is%3Aq

Comment: I'm done with the 4 remaining ones. Fingers crossed all suggested edits get approved (if not: I will NOT re-submit suggestions for them ... And I'd consider it bizar). After these 4 get (all) approved, I'll look at the remaining query (with those 108 questions), to see if I can find any in there that I can tackle also.

Comment: Voilà, we now even have a tag excerpt for "guide", including a pointer to the "documentation" tag ...

Comment: @dsolimano and Pierre: I purged the MATLAB-related posts in the [guide] tag, see my post below. We could use some discussion regarding the rest of the posts in [guide], let me know what you think.

Comment: "Guides" still exists as of today.

Comment: Pierre, @dsolimano: FYI [tag:guide] will be dead at midnight (see also the update to my answer). Let's hope it doesn't come back from the dead to haunt us later.

Comment: @AndrasDeak an exciting day

Comment: @AndrasDeak merci beacoup for all your efforts! Does that mean you want me to post a similar question for some other tag (to keep you busy for another 2 years again)?

Comment: Haha, you guys are horrible:D (cc @dsolimano)

Answer (score 15):

Almost two years after [the first misplaced request on MSE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250948/remove-the-guide) and almost a year after this fixing attempt, we still need a disambiguation [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/guide).

Here's what [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/guide) was about when writing this post:

- created 7 years ago, info page viewed 9 times
- no tag wiki
- sloppy short tag description:

  > Use this tag for questions about 'guide', used in the context of
  >   'Matlab'. Do not use this tag for questions about install guides, user
  >   guides, etc (use tag 'documentation' for those questions instead).
- 186 questions, 84 tagged [matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab)

### Update January 2016

I've managed to weed out every MATLAB-related question tagged [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/guide). I've also submitted a tag wiki edit:

*Tag wiki excerpt*:

> DO NOT USE THIS AMBIGUOUS TAG! If the question concerns MATLAB GUIDE, use [matlab-guide] instead. If it concerns documentations, the [documentation] tag may apply.

*Tag wiki*:

**THIS IS AN AMBIGUOUS TAG THAT SHOULD NOT BE USED**

- Questions concerning the MATLAB GUIDE should be tagged [matlab-guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab-guide) instead
- Questions concerning documentation should be tagged with [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/documentation) instead
- General questions concerning tutorials are off-topic on Stack Overflow

(with an additional link to this meta discussion)

---

I believe the remainder of the [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/guide) tag is almost entirely useless. I believe it mostly correlates with opinion-based or other off-topic questions at best, and it is a meta-tag at worst. I *think* that without the MATLAB-related questions the tag should be burninated, then blacklisted. People *will* start tagging both kinds of questions as [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/guide), since even much less subtle mistakes are constantly being made on SO.

*However*, I've seen a few problematic cases, which advise caution, for instance:

- [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15328134/guiders-js-guider-showing-over-element) is tagged [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/guide) but concerns itself with JS Guiders. I couldn't quickly find an appropriate tag
- [this (closed) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340853/im-getting-listless-and-worried-ill-lose-my-passion) is *only* tagged [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/guide). I'm aware of the [untagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged) tag that applies to such questions if the tag is burninated, but this might be worth mentioning.

So currently it's still up for discussion what should be done with the remainder of [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/guide). Can it be demolished automatically by a mod/employee? And if so, *should* it? There are a hundred questions left, still not too much, but almost all of those questions are off-topic and need more work. Running out of MATLAB, I feel unauthorized to proceed.

### Update April 2017

Since the last update I've been on the lookout for newly asked questions tagged with [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/guide), retagging and close-voting as necessary. As the older questions slowly got retagged or closed and deleted, the number of questions tagged with [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/guide) slowly decayed to 30, after which the rest was cleaned up in a shorter push. Off-topic questions left in the tag have been closed and deleted, on-topic ones have been retagged. Thanks for everyone who chipped in.

So as of April 2017 there are 0 questions tagged with [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/guide). Let's hope it stays this way, especially since the above deprecating tag wiki won't be reproduced if the tag gets recreated.

Comment: Beautiful stuff!  I'm personally for working through and retagging.  I haven't seen the hunger games, but I feel there's some joke about volunteering myself that could be made.

Comment: @dsolimano Awesome, thanks, glad to hear that. (Sorry for the late reply, your comment was lost in an unexpected heap of notifications.). I have a hunch that if we start on this, most of the retags would also need a CV as off-topic. By the way, current [tag:guide] count is 96 questions.

Comment: It would also be wise to decide what should be done with blatantly off-topic questions in the tag. Retagging with [documentation] would be a bit like shooting ourselves in the leg. I think those questions (which are mostly requests for tutorials) should just be *un*tagged and CVed, and *re*tagging should be kept as a last resort for actual valid questions about documentation.

Comment: agreed, there's no point in leaving them open

Answer (score 6):

Personally, I would get rid of the documentation-style usage of [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/guide), because I don't think anyone is an expert in "guides" in general.

For the Matlab questions, I would retag the questions to something like [matlab-guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab-guide) as you suggest.  Are there similar tags for other matlab functions we can use as a reference?

I can pitch in on retags if the community agrees, or at least doesn't disagree.  The last tag I killed was [serial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/serial), it was very satisfying to watch it die. HAHAHAHAHA.  Ok, maybe I need to get out more.

Comment: Sounds like a plan to me. Also, count me in as 1 member of that community (I'm interested in more details about the retagging stuff). All I know for now about it is like so: (a) on meta there is a retag-tag (but I don't quite get it from there) and (b) in my early SE-days, with about 0 rep, I started adding tags (only) as suggested edits, or changing (only) tags, all of them (like 10 or so?) got rejected (I was just trying to help though ... how nice!) and (c) moderators (or similar) seem to have mass-retag tools or something, but do they get "rewarded" for doing retagging?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens You have to be careful as a user with less than 2000 reputation to participate in such a retag action. Whenever you suggest an edit, it goes into a review queue where 3 users have to agree that it was a good edit. Although we don't have a "too minor" reject reason anymore, it is usually frowned upon to simply do the retag without also fixing up everything else in the post. Give the other tags on questions a stern look, fix formatting and grammar. Make the title as clear as possible. Whenever you see a bad question, flag it for closure and maybe hold off on a retag.

Comment: So you are the [tag:serial]Killer? Ohhh the fear... ;)

Comment: @ArtjomB. Thank you for this advice, it's an expanded version of what I was referring to in my (b) item of my previous comment. And therefor "I" am going to be very carefull, and will probably only really participate in such retag operation after I don't have a risk anymore of running into rejected edits. I've been there, I know how it is like, I know the rule like "if (rejects - (approves/3) > 5) then you-are-out-for-7-days" ... And I know how to prevent it: first work on like X suggested edits in which you don't take any risk. So that it becomes like "if (rejects > X/3 +5) then ..." (X=61 !)

Comment: @EMBarbosa: who is the "you" in your comment? Also: I don't "get it", probably because I'm fairly new ... 2nd try?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I'm the serial killer, ha!